# GStreamer: receive/demultiplex multiple RTP streams on one port?

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I'd like to use gstreamer to create a network sink for multiple UDP RTP streams. The basic setup (one sender, one receiver) works fine and looks like this:

```
# sender:
gst-launch-1.0 -vvtcm audiotestsrc ! rtpgstpay config-interval=1 ssrc=1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
# receiver:
gst-launch-1.0 -vvtcm udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=application,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=X-GST" ! rtpssrcdemux ! rtpgstdepay ! autoaudiosink
```

However, I would like to have multiple senders that can dynamically start and stop streaming to the same port. AFAICT the SSRC field in RTP allows me to do exactly this, but I can't figure out how to configure `rtpssrcdemux` so that it will create additional sink pads.

E.g. when I start the following receiver pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvtcm udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=application,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=X-GST" ! rtpssrcdemux name=demux demux.src_0 ! rtpgstdepay ! autoaudiosink demux.src_1 ! rtpgstdepay ! autoaudiosink
```

it will wait for the first audio stream, but when I start a second sender with a different SSRC, the pipeline stops with `streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)`.

Hints welcome...?

Comment: Hope you found the answer here, new-ssrc-pad signal of rtpssrcdemux should help here I hope but it can be done only via code/api I guess, Please let me know if that's the right way

Answer (score 0):

For the record (and a few years late ;-), this is not possible using gst-launch alone, you need code to listen for the `new-ssrc-pad` signal as mentioned in the comment.